# Codeigniter usign cusotm Library in Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a weird problem and i can't figure out how to solve it...

I have a custom library **User.php** with de following code:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User
{
    public $session_prefix = 'usrs_';

    public $cookie_prefix = 'usrc_';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->model('users_model');

        $this->users_model->login_remembered_user();
    }

    public function __get($var)
    {
        return get_instance()->$var;
    }
    
    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the model **Users_model.php** with the following code:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login_remembered_user()
    {
        $cookie_id = $this->user->cookie_prefix . 'id';
        $cookie_rc = $this->user->cookie_prefix . 'rc';

        if($this->user->is_logged_in() && get_cookie($cookie_id) && get_cookie($cookie_rc))
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the model at method **login_remembered_user** i get the error that class **user** isn't set, although the **user** library is autoloaded...

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Load your library manually to check if it's work if you include it

Comment: The problem is not in the library, it is loaded ok.. the problem is in the model, $this->user in the model is null...

Comment: Please show the code which loads in your library.

Comment: In config/autoload.php i have: `$autoload['library'] = array('user');`